# Is there a way to cancel a context after a delay after one goroutine returns?

Tags: go, asynchronous, timeout, goroutine, go-context

## Problem

#### Situation

I currently have a gin handler function that runs three separate queries in three separate goroutines using the same context. There is an err group (`"golang.org/x/sync/errgroup"`) that uses this shared context and the handler waits for the err group before returning.

### Objective

The behavior I am trying to implement is after one of the goroutines finishes, there should be a timeout enforced on the remaining goroutines, but also this context should also be cancelled if the gin request is cancelled (connection closed), meaning gin's `ctx.Request.Context()` would have to be used.

## Potential Solutions

### Current implementation

Currently, I have a context with timeout passed to an errgroup but this just enforces a timeout for all the goroutines.

```golang
timeoutCtx := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
g, err := errgroup.WithContext(timeoutCtx)

g.Go(func1)
g.Go(func2)
g.Go(func3)

err = g.Wait()
```

Using the gin request context is required so that if the connection is closed and the request is cancelled, the goroutines will also stop.

```golang
// ctx *gin.Context
g, err := errgroup.WithContext(ctx.Request.Context())

g.Go(func1)
g.Go(func2)
g.Go(func3)

err = g.Wait()
```

### Using a channel to implement timeout

[Source](https://gobyexample.com/timeouts)

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {

    c1 := make(chan string, 1)
    go func() {
        time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
        c1 <- "result 1"
    }()

    select {
    case res := <-c1:
        fmt.Println(res)
    case <-time.After(1 * time.Second):
        fmt.Println("timeout 1")
    }

    c2 := make(chan string, 1)
    go func() {
        time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
        c2 <- "result 2"
    }()
    select {
    case res := <-c2:
        fmt.Println(res)
    case <-time.After(3 * time.Second):
        fmt.Println("timeout 2")
    }
}
```

### Combining channels and request context

This solution is close but not very elegant or complete.

```golang
cQueryDone := make(chan bool)

g, err := errgroup.WithContext(ctx.Request.Context())

g.Go(func1)
g.Go(func2)
g.Go(func3)

// assumes func1 func2 and func3 all have cQueryDone <- true

if <-cQueryDone {
    select {
        case <-cQueryDone:
            select {
                case <-cQueryDone:
                    // ctx.JSON
                    // return
                case <-time.After(1*time.Second):
                    // ctx.JSON
                    // return
            }
        case <-time.After(3*time.Second):
            // ctx.JSON
            // return
    }
}

err = g.Wait()
```

Is there a better and more idiomatic way to implement this behavior in Go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `context.WithTimeout()` :

- can wrap any context (not just `context.Background()`)
- also returns a `cancel` function

You can add a timeout on top of `ctx.Request.Context()`, and call `cancel` when any of the queries completes :

```
timeoutCtx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(ctx.Request.Context())

g, err := errgroup.WithContext(timeoutCtx)

g.Go( func1(cancel) ) // pass the cancel callback to each query some way or another
g.Go( func2(cancel) ) // you prabably want to also pass timeoutCtx
g.Go( func3(cancel) )

g.Wait()
```

---

Following your comment : there is also `context.WithCancel()`, and you can call cancel after a delay

```
childCtx, cancel := context.WithCancel(ctx.Request.Context())

g, err := errgroup.WithContext(childCtx)

hammerTime := func(){
    <-time.After(1*time.Second)
    cancel()
}

g.Go( func1(hammerTime) ) // funcXX should have access to hammerTime
g.Go( func2(hammerTime) )
g.Go( func3(hammerTime) )

g.Wait()
```

Comment: This is close to what I am looking for, thank you! The only difference is the timeout should be enforced when one of the queries completes. Until any one query completes, there should be no timeout enforced, the only way to cancel if none of the queries complete is if the request context is cancelled.

In this example it looks like if any of the funcs call cancel the rest will be cancelled immediately.